# Unity 3d Android when turn phone problems

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

i have 2 problems with my project.

My joystick and text (canvas items) are in wrong positions after i build my project. And items more little than before i build. (they are become small)
(ps: im using anchor)

My second problem is when i turn phone, background has become black. (not all black but black sides are seems)

i will add two photo from game.

[from game 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7X1y.jpg)

[when turn phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJW3C.jpg)

I need really help for these problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your UI elements does not scale correctly with different screens.
To solve this you can use the [Canvas-Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html).

Read it for better understanding, but in general, you have to do something like that:

1. On your project, select your Canvas.
2. Change the UI Scale Mode to
   **Scale With Screen Size**.
3. Choose the Reference Resolution to your liking. I also suggest to choose Screen Match Mode of: **Match Width
   or Height**.
4. Set the **Match** slider all the way to either
   Width or Height, depends on which one is more important on your game.
   From the attached images I feel like your game is based on Height,
   but you'll have to see what feels better for you.

The resulting settings should look something like that:
[IMAGE (suggested canvas settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sImaW.png)

Now you have to test different extreme aspect-ratios **AND** different resolutions. Luckily, the editor let you do it via the first tab on the Game screen:
[IMAGE (aspect ratio tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkEkh.png)

So you can adjust your canvas settings and specific UI elements accordingly.
If you still have problems with a specific element, check it's [Rect-Trunsform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html) settings.

Good luck.